# Azure - How to identify any NSG associated to a specific NIC or VM?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-powershell, network-security-groups

I am trying to delete EVERY resource associated with a specific VM that I created with PowerShell. I also managed to write a script that deletes the VM, disk, NIC, and public IP but i can't identify the automatically created NetworkSecurityGroup with it (just enables RDP).
From what I see the NSG is connected to the NetworkInterface (at least it says "Associated with: 0 subnets, 1 network interface in portal.azure.com) so top town its
"vNet" --> VM --> "NIC" --> "NSG"(s)

I managed to loop through NetworkInterfaces with:

```
foreach($nicUri in $vm.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces.Id) {}
```

So i tried similar stuff like:

```
$nsg = $vm.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces.NetworkSecurityGroup.Id
```

...in every version i could think about. Doesn't even get me an error. It's just empty.

Do you guys have ANY idea of what i am looking at here? Would be very happy about any tip i can get!

Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 0):

One tip, if possible, is to create each VM in its own resource group along with the NSG. That way all you have to do when you are done is delete the resource group which will delete all the associated resources in a single command.

Get-AzResourceGroup -Name "ContosoRG01" | Remove-AzResourceGroup -Force